# Consuming StackExchange API with Angular

Tags: angular, rest, api

I try to display questions from this website, but get errors in the console: 
ERROR TypeError: Object expected
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Here's my service:

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

searchUrl: string = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=";

getSearchResults(searchQuery: string): Observable<searchResultsFromAPI[]> {
    return this._http.get<{items: any[]}>(`${this.searchUrl}${searchQuery}&site=stackoverflow`).map(data=>data.items);
}
}
```

And the component:

```
constructor (private getSearchService: StackSearchService) { }

objectKeys = Object.keys;

searchItem = "";
questionsList: searchResultsFromAPI[];

getSearchResults(): void {
       this.getSearchService.getSearchResults(this.searchItem).subscribe(questions => this.questionsList = questions);
   console.log(this.searchItem);
}
```

in the component view I just call `getSearchResults()` then click the search button.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete error log?

Comment: Hi, solved it. Thanks ayway

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I didn't put the correct type that the API returns in the get. So I looked again at the API and here's how I do it now, and it works:

```
return this._http.get<{has_more: boolean, items: any[], quota_max: number, quota_remaining: number}>
```